# How do I sort each row of a 2D array separately?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to make a program where users have to enter a list of 100 numbers.
The outcome has to be a 2 dimensional matrix with with 34 rows and 3 columns (where the last row has only 1 number of course).
Now I want to: first sort the array by ascending order. Then I want to sort each row separately by descending order.

I'll demonstrate with a two dimensional array containing 10 elements

If these are the numbers the user enters: 2, 4, 6, 9, 5, 2, 3, 4, 9, 7
I want the array to look like this:

```
    3 2 2
    5 4 4
    9 7 6
    9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to start with a 1D array which you can later copy to a 2D array if you really have to.

```
Array.Sort(input); //input is an int[100]
//Now, sort each row in descending order
var comparer = Comparer<int>.Create((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));
for (int row = 0; row < 99; r+=3) {
    Array.Sort(input, row, 3, comparer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward if you do the sorting and restructuring as separate steps:

1. Collect the results in a flat (i.e. one-dimensional) array.
2. Sort the flat array (e.g. with `Array.Sort(...)`).
3. Build up your new data structure by looping through the flat array. You don't need to do any further sorting here. Each time just take `[arr[n+2], arr[n+1], arr[n]]` as the row in the new 2D array and jump forward to `n = n + 3`.

Answer (score 0):

I also favour creating the output structure by looping over the sorted input structure. The following will achieve what you want. It will take any size array of integers and the required number of columns for the two-dimensional output array and return the result as you defined it.

```
public static int?[,] SortInput(int[] input, int requiredColumnCount)
{
    // Guard conditions.
    if (input == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));

    if (input.Length < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(input));

    if (requiredColumnCount < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(requiredColumnCount));

    var inputLength = input.Length;

    // Sort the input array in ascending order.
    Array.Sort(input);

    // Dimension the output array.
    var requiredRowCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)inputLength / requiredColumnCount);
    var output = new int?[requiredRowCount, requiredColumnCount];

    // Setup variables to check for special handling of last output row.
    var lastRowIndex = output.GetUpperBound(0);
    var columnCountForLastRow = inputLength % requiredColumnCount;

    // Populate the output array.
    for (var inputIndex = 0; inputIndex < inputLength; inputIndex += requiredColumnCount)
    {
        var rowIndex = inputIndex / requiredColumnCount;

        // Special handling may be required if there are insufficient
        // input values to fully populate the last output row.
        if ((rowIndex == lastRowIndex) && (columnCountForLastRow != 0))
            requiredColumnCount = columnCountForLastRow;

        for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < requiredColumnCount; columnIndex++)
        {
            output[rowIndex, columnIndex] = input[inputIndex + requiredColumnCount - columnIndex - 1];
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```